# How to find if the numbers are continuous in R?

Tags: r, statistics

I have a range of values

```
c(1,2,3,4,5,8,9,10,13,14,15)
```

And I want to find the ranges where the numbers become discontinuous. All I want is this as output:

```
(1,5)
(8,10)
(13,15)
```

I need to find break points.

I need to do it in R.

Comment: Why is (1,5) an expected output when you have a break between 1 and 5? There's no 4 in your values.

Comment: Changed it. Just an oversight.

Comment: Yeah, I found a solution in Python but I am doing this in R.

Comment: I would like to see your Python solution for this: @thecoder16

Answer (score 6):

Something like this?

```
x <- c(1:5, 8:10, 13:15) # example data
unname(tapply(x, cumsum(c(1, diff(x)) != 1), range)
# [[1]]
# [1] 1 5
# 
# [[2]]
# [1]  8 10
# 
# [[3]]
# [1] 13 15
```

Another example:

```
x <- c(1, 5, 10, 11:14, 20:21, 23)
unname(tapply(x, cumsum(c(1, diff(x)) != 1), range))
# [[1]]
# [1] 1 1
#
# [[2]]
# [1] 5 5
#
# [[3]]
# [1] 10 14
#
# [[4]]
# [1] 20 21
#
# [[5]]
# [1] 23 23
```

Answer (score 5):

```
x <- c(1:5, 8:10, 13:15)    
rr <- rle(x - seq_along(x))
rr$values <- seq_along(rr$values)
s <- split(x, inverse.rle(rr))
s
# $`1`
# [1] 1 2 3 4 5
# 
# $`2`
# [1]  8  9 10
# 
# $`3`
# [1] 13 14 15

## And then to get *literally* what you asked for:
cat(paste0("(", gsub(":", ",", sapply(s, deparse)), ")"), sep="\n")
# (1,5)
# (8,10)
# (13,15)
```

Comment: Could maybe split by x-seq_along(x) instead of using rle?

Comment: @user20650 -- The problem is that wouldn't be safe for vectors like this: `x <- c(1:5, 8:10, 9:11)`. (See what you then get when doing `split(x, x-seq_along(x))`).

Answer (score 1):

I published `seqle` which will do this for you in one line.  You can load the package `cgwtools` or search SO for the code, as it's been posted a couple times.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you don't care about the exact output and are looking for the min and max of each range, you can use diff/cumsum/range as follows:

```
x  <- c(1:5, 8:10, 13:15)
x. <- c(0, cumsum( diff(x)-1 ) ) 

lapply( split(x, x.), range )
```