# R: Group number string to from-to form

Tags: r

I have (after a long script) a value/vector that look like

```
258  814  815  816  817  818  819  862  863  864  865  866  867  868
869  870  871  872  1377 1378 1379 1393 1394 1395 1396 1397 1398
1399 1400 ........
```

This is quite difficult to get controll over. So I would like if there was some way to get it to

```
258
814-819
862-872
1377-1379
1393-1400
and so on....
```

I have thought about some sort of for loop that adds value to string if x[i+1]!=x[i]+1, but this can take some time if the dataset is large...

For input

```
x <- c(258, 814:819, 862:872, 1377:1379, 1393:1400)
```

The output should be

```
"258\n814-819\n862-872\n1377-1379\n1393-1400"
```

Comment: What is the pattern you want to follow?  Which numbers should be linked or treated as a group?

Comment: To group the values which have a value next to it. So that 1,2,3,4 => 1-4 and 1,2,3,5,6,7 => 1-3,5-7

Comment: `x[cumsum(rle(diff(x))$length) + 1]` is a start, though it misses the first value.

Comment: [this question might help](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23095415/how-to-find-if-the-numbers-are-continuous-in-r/23095698#comment35302617_23095698)

Comment: You could try: `c(by(x, cumsum(c(TRUE,diff(x)!=1)), FUN=function(.x) if(length(.x) >1) paste(.x[1], .x[length(.x)], sep="-") else .x))`

Comment: Or maybe `temp <- x[cumsum(rle(diff(x))$length) + 1] ; c(x[1], paste0(temp[c(T,F)], "-", temp[c(F,T)]))`

Comment: Thanks to all! Awesome that so many people came up with different methods that all worked in such short time! Went with a combination of Josh and charles methods (and added some of my own to look as I wanted in my case)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding on to [Josh's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23095415/how-to-find-if-the-numbers-are-continuous-in-r/23095698#comment35302617_23095698) this should work:

```
rr <- rle(x - seq_along(x))
rr$values <- seq_along(rr$values)
s <- split(x, inverse.rle(rr))

paste(lapply(s, FUN = function(x) if(length(x) > 1){paste(x[1], x[length(x)], sep="-")}else{x}), collapse="\n")

[1] "258\n814-819\n862-872\n1377-1379\n1393-1400"
```

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the options above and at the linked question, there is also `seqToHumanReadable` from the "R.utils" package:

```
library(R.utils)
seqToHumanReadable(x)
# [1] "258, 814-819, 862-872, 1377-1379, 1393-1400"
```

To get your exact desired output, use `gsub`:

```
gsub(",\\s+", "\n", seqToHumanReadable(x))
# [1] "258\n814-819\n862-872\n1377-1379\n1393-1400"
```